# Docker compose mapping local directory to dockerfile volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using an Apache / MySql Docker-compose set up which is all good. However the issue comes when, as this is for local development, the web container points to a local folder, for which I need Apache to have permissions to.

Using

```
RUN mkdir /www \
&& chown -R apache:apache /www

VOLUME ["/www"]
```

is fine if I run the Apache dockerfile by itself or if I run it in docker-compose without specifying a volume. But this means that I can't point that volume at a local directory, in this scenario "www" exists inside the container but doesn't map to the host machine. If I specify a volume inside the docker-compose file then it maps as expected but doesn't allow me to CHOWN the folder / files (even if I exec into the container)

Below is a proof of concept, I'm running on Windows 10 / Docker Desktop Community Version 2.0.0.0-win81 (29211)

EDIT (commented exposing the port, built the dockerfile from docker-compose and changed the port to 80 from 81)

EDIT (I've updated the following files, see bottom, I'm leaving these for posterity)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes: 
    - ./:/www
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:centos6 as stage1

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all \
    && yum --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y yum-utils \
    httpd \
    php

FROM stage1 as stage2
RUN mkdir /www \
    && chown -R apache:apache /www 

#VOLUME ["/www"]

#EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

UPDATED Proof of concept files

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes: 
    - ./:/www
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:centos6

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all \
    && yum --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y yum-utils \
    httpd \
    php

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e #exit straight away if there's an issue

chown -R apache:apache /www

# Apache
/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Comment: Why are you defining the www volume twice?

Comment: Also mkdir www makes no sense since that's a volume so it'll just be overwritten. Any changes you want to make to a volume directory should be done from entrypoint after the volume is made by docker-compose

Comment: You're also both exposing port 80 to 80 and mapping 81:80 which is confusing, I'd guess that you don't want to do that and this is a mistake. If you did want to do that though you should do both from the compose.yml file not one from yml and one in the dockerfile

Comment: Another thing, you're defining an image not a build in your yml file which is strange to say the least. Are you building the image from the docker file then using docker-compose just to work off of that image?

Sorry for all the comments, I just keep seeing strange stuff

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton www is defined in the buildfile so that I have somewhere in the Apache container I know the name of.
81:80 was just a local config change (I was running something on port 80 on the host)
I guess I should have been clearer for the proof of concept I am building the dockerfile as "poc" then i use that as the image in the docker compose file

Comment: You define the www volume in both the yml and dockerfile. If you're running on port 81 then you don't need EXPOSE 80 in your dockerfile as well as the 81:80 map in your yml. Yes but why not let docker-compose build the image for you and simplify the whole process?

Comment: Normally the reason is that it's a development environment where you don't want to have to rebuild constantly @MyHeadHurts however I of course don't know why OP has chosen to do it in his case in particular

Comment: Like i say this is just the proof of concept so not worried about the ports etc. It works from a port point of view as it is.

edit: Like I say this is proof of concept in the real file I point to a remote docker repository for the image but that shouldnt affect the volume problem

@MyHeadHurts  georgeappleton is right that the idea is to be able to edits to files on the host machine

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton I've made the edits to the dockerfile / docker-compose to save any confusion  but as you would expect that doesn't change the fundamental issue. 

Also I run with 

    docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate -V

Comment: @Scrambledheads actually that will definitely affect the volume problem. Currently you're mapping your `.` directory to `www` in docker-compose. If you want each machine to do that with the image given (like you say you do) then you should remove `VOLUME ["/www"]` from your dockerfile. I'm going to post an answer because your main issue is your incorrect usage of mkdir and chown. Fix that and you should fix the problem

Comment: I've edited my original post / proof of concept removing the volume declaration from the dockerfile.

I hope this is a clean example to show my issue which is want to have a docker container with a known directory (parent folder) that maps to a folder on the host machine. This is to allow working editing local files inside of "apache" along the lines of Vagrant.

The real set up has a mysql container, phpmyadmin container and an apache container running via docker-compose. With the files being served from the apache container from the host machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker for Windows uses a CIFS/Samba network file share to bind-mount host files into the Linux VM running docker. That is always done as `root:root` so all bind-mount files/dirs will always show that when seen from inside container. This is a [known limitation of the way docker shares these files between the OS's](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/39).

Workarounds:

1. In many cases, this isn't an issue. The host files are shared into the container world-readable, so local app development while running in the container is fine. For cache files, user uploads, etc. just be sure they are written into a container path that isn't to the host-bind mount, so they stay in Linux where you can control the perms.
2. If needed, for development only, run the app in the container as root if it needs write permissions to host OS files. You can override this at runtime: e.g. `docker run -u root` or `user:root` in `docker-compose.yml`
3. For working with database files, don't bind-mount them, but use named volumes to keep the files in the Linux VM. You can always use `docker cp` to copy files in and out of volumes for a quick backup.

Comment: Thanks, I think for my specific use case(s) I will have to use 1, 3 and or cry.

Answer (score 1):

You're using

`RUN mkdir /www \
&& chown -R apache:apache /www`

Prior to docker-compose mapping the local `.` directory to `www`.

You need to create a file entrypoint.sh or similar. Give it a shbang. And inside that you should run `chown -R apache:apache /www`. You do not need the mkdir as that's created by docker compose volume config `./:/www`.

After that command in your entrypoint.sh file you should add in what you currently have for your entrypoint `/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`.

Then finally you of course need to set your new entrypoint to use the entrypoint.sh file `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, just checking it resolves the issue before marking it as the answer

Comment: tried 

`COPY ./entrypoint.sh /`
`ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]`


and entrypoint as 
`#!/bin/bash`
`set -e #exit straight away if there's an issue`
`chown -R apache:apache /www`
`/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`

but when I exec in ls -l still shows www as owned by root

Comment: Use the `docker logs` command to check that your chown function is working correctly. Also try running the entrypoint.sh command from your `exec bash` cli or running chown from there just to see if you can debug the issue. I assume `set -e` won't suppress any errors, I've never used it so I don't know about its usage apart from what I just read on the man page. Another note, are you sure that `/www` is the correct directory? www isn't normally found at root `/`. Also worth checking that the user:group apache:apache both exist and are what your image use. Normally it's www-data:www-data.

Comment: I thought I'd said but I had / have tried exec and I get (before and now) the same result.

www is just the root of the webserver for my real set up(it can be anything but I have config files that make it that).

`cat /etc/passwd` gives me the following
`...
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin`


`cat etc/group` gives me 
`...
apache:x:48:`

docker logs gives me nothing (not literally but it just shows "httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,..."

Comment: chown shouldn't just be silently failing, this isn't a docker setup problem if you can't get chown to work while `exec bash`ed into the container.

Comment: The reason I believe its a docker issue is if I run the dockerfile without dockercompose it works...

Comment: That's because your dockerfile doesn't use a mapped volume by itself, it would've just created a regular directory and chowned it. With the full usage of docker-compose are you able to chown other directories?

Comment: Are you able to change the owner of the directory on your local (without sudo)? The binded copy should be practically the same as the local one. And root in the container should have all of the permissions of the user who launched the container.

Comment: As I say I'm running Windows 10 (with Linux containers) it is just the default Linux vm created by Docker (I reset it to factory settings all the time)

Comment: That would explain it then, you won't be able to change the permissions on a windows machine like that because it's a volume bound to a real local directory. All changes to the volume on docker also need to happen to the bound version locally which is simply impossible for windows. You'll likely need to change over to use `COPY`, change to linux (or maybe a mac), or run a virtual machine with docker inside (surprisingly common due to issues like this). It's also worth noting, if you used COPY, you may still edit the files without rebuilding if you find the volume location on your drive.

Comment: You also may not be able to do that if you find the volume, it may have the same issues as before. I don't know how windows handles volumes compared to linux. For serious development you're better going with linux over windows anyway so this may be a blessing in disguise.

Comment: Docker (on Windows) uses (creates) a Linux vm for this so it is using Linux; just as if you installed Docker in a VM (or should be) so I would argue either this is *still* a bug in Docker or (more likely) I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Okay, so can you change the directory owner on the linux vm?

Comment: No idea but that wouldn't help. As I say it's a docker created VM. Then that maps through to a folder on Windows (where the files are) the docker process has permissions to the windows folder

Comment: Sounds very messy :/ for testing purposes try disabling the volume and instead using COPY to get the files in. See if you can chown that. If you can then I suspect the issue is windows permissions since it all bubbles up from the linux stuff to the windows machine directory anyway