# Docker-compose Apache mapping external local directory to document root

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose

I am pretty beginner with Docker, and I'm trying to create a local development LAMP (more exactly Apache, MariaDB, PHP) stack using docker-compose, existing Docker images from Docker hub and no Dockerfile if possible, to be used with several local web projects.

I'd like to map my local web project directory `/Users/myusername/projects/myprojectname` to the default document root for Apache container (which seems to be `/app` for the [Apache image I'm using](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-apache))

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8889:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=localmysqluser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=localmysqlpwd
  php:
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:7.4
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - /Users/myusername/projects/myprojectname:/app
  apache:
    image: bitnami/apache:latest
    container_name: apache
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./apache-vhosts/myapp.conf:/vhosts/myapp.conf:ro
      - /Users/myusername/projects/myprojectname:/app
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - php
```

But when I do `docker-compose up -d` then browse to `http://localhost:8080/`, I get zero data. Where am I wrong? Is my `docker-compose.yml` configuration wrong, or is it because of system rights?

I've been looking at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649873/docker-compose-mapping-local-directory-to-dockerfile-volume), but I'd prefer not using any Dockerfile if possible.

Further question: is it possible to make a local directory `/Users/myusername/projects/` browsable by Apache in my local browser?

Comment: Exposed port number of apache image is `8080`. Change port mapping of apache service to `8080:8080` and try again.

Comment: Indeed! Now it works, except it doesn't run PHP scripts, but that's another story. Thanks!

Comment: @J. Song don't hesitate to post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by [J. Song](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17577431/j-song), exposed port number of this Apache Docker image is 8080, not 80.

So we just need to change port mapping of Apache service to `8080:8080` instead of `8080:80`.